# Using whois rubygem with -h flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whois

Is there a way to use the whois gem (https://github.com/weppos/whois) with a `-h` flag? I am looking to run whois queries against a specific database host in my rails project (e.g. `whois -h whois.myserver.example google.com`)

If not, are there other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/whois/Whois/Client

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> settings (Hash) (defaults to: {}) —
>
> Hash of settings to customize the client behavior.
> ```
>
> Options Hash (settings):
>
> ```
> :timeout (Integer, nil) — default: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT —
>
> The timeout for a WHOIS query, expressed in seconds.
> :bind_host (String) — default: nil —
>
> Providing an IP address or hostname will bind the Socket connection to the specific local host.
> :bind_port (Fixnum) — default: nil —
>
> Providing port number will bind the Socket connection to the specific local port.
> :host (String, nil) — default: nil —
>
> The server host to query. Leave it blank for intelligent detection.
> ```

So

```
client = Whois::Client.new(:host => "whois.myserver.example")
```

should be what you need.
No idea if you need to change the port too.